# Intent not restored correctly after activity is killed if clear top and single top flags are supplied

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application there is an activity started using the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) and [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flags because I want to make sure that only one instance of that activity is at the top of the stack and all activities on top of the old instance are closed. So far so good.

Next I wanted to test if the activity restores correctly after being created more than once and successively destroyed. I take care to manually set the intent using [`Activity.setIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) when [`Activity.onNewIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) is called so that the most recent intent is returned by [`Activity.getIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29). In order to test that I activated the "Don't keep activities" option in the developer options, but the intent returned by [`Activity.getIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29) when the activity is re-created is the very first intent that created it and not the most recent one.

This happens on JB and ICS, I haven't tested it on older versions. Am I doing something wrong or did I misunderstand something in the docs?

Answer (score 18):

If you kill your app while it is in the foreground, this is not the same as when Android kills your app (which it will only do when your app is in the background). If you kill and then restart the app, it is like starting it all over again from scratch. There is no "restore" going on here. If you add logging to `onCreate()` you should see that after you kill and restart your app, the `Bundle` that is passed to `onCreate()` is null.

Unfortunately it is pretty difficult to simulate what happens when Android kills your app.

**EDIT: Added more stuff after OP's comment**

Here's a concrete example for discussion purposes. First **without** the developer option "Don't keep activities":

- `ActivityA` is the root activity
- We start `ActivityA`
- `ActivityA.onCreate()` is called
- `ActivityA` now starts `ActivityB`
- `ActivityB.onCreate()` is called (The activity stack now contains `ActivityA`->`ActivityB`)
- `ActivityB` starts `ActivityA` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and an extra "foo"
- `ActivityA.onNewIntent()` gets called with the `Intent` containing `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and an extra "foo"
- `ActivityB.onDestroy()` is called since the activity stack was cleared back to `ActivityA`

Now, let's do the exact same thing but enable the developer option "Don't keep activities"  (I've highlighted in **bold** the stuff that is different from the previous scenario):

- `ActivityA` is the root activity
- We start `ActivityA`
- `ActivityA.onCreate()` is called
- `ActivityA` now starts `ActivityB`
- `ActivityB.onCreate()` is called (The activity stack now contains `ActivityA`->`ActivityB`)
- **Because `ActivityA` has stopped, Android destroys it and calls `ActivityA.onDestroy()`**
- **Note: The activity stack still contains `ActivityA`->`ActivityB`, even though there is no instance of `ActivityA` at the moment. Android remembers all the state**
- `ActivityB` starts `ActivityA` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and an extra "foo"
- **Since Android has no instance of `ActivityA` to reactivate, it needs to create one, so it does and then...**
- **`ActivityA.onCreate()` is called with the same `Intent` that it was called with when the original instance of `ActivityA` was created (ie: LAUNCH intent with no flags and no extras)**
- `ActivityA.onNewIntent()` gets called with the `Intent` containing `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and an extra "foo"
- `ActivityB.onDestroy()` is called since the activity stack was cleared back to `ActivityA`

The important thing to note here is that Android always calls `onCreate()` whenever it creates an activity instance. Think of it like the **constructor** of an `Activity`. If Android has to recreate an instance of an `Activity` because the process was killed or the activity was destroyed, then it will instantiate a new object, then call `onCreate()` and then (if necessary) it will call `onNewIntent()`.

When you call `setIntent()` this doesn't actually change the `Intent` that Android saves and restores. That only changes the in-memory `Intent` that will be returned from a call to `getIntent()`.

I hope this is clearer now. If not, please let me know.

Comment: I didn't describe how the activity is killed correctly. I just edited my question.

Comment: I find your last statement - which is totally correct, that's what Android does - a bit confusing. Why the framework should save the very first intent and not the last one? By adding those flags my intention is typically to let ActivityA show some different content. But if it's killed and then restored using the first intent I'll end up seeing old content.

One amendment to what you wrote: after you kill and restart your app, the Bundle that is passed to `onCreate()` is not null if you saved something on `onSavedInstanceState()`.

Comment: Maybe you are still missing something. Android saves both the first `Intent` (ie: the one used when calling `onCreate()`) and it also saves the last one. If the activity needs to be reinstantiated, it uses the saved "first" `Intent`, but then immediately after that it calls `onNewIntent()` with the most recent one. So I don't understand why you say you will end up seeing old content? The most recent `Intent` gets delivered to your app via `onNewIntent()` before `onResume()` gets called. So after a kill/restore your app should show the last content.

Comment: There is an extra thing I observe in "Don't keep activities" mode. If you follow the exact procedure, and end up on Activity A, then press home, and then select recent activities, and return to Activity A the OS will call onCreate with the very fist Intent (without foo), and onNewIntent won't be called.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you've found a solution to this or not, but overriding the onNewIntent(Intent theNewIntent) method for the target activity & calling setIntent(theNewIntent) solved it for me.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    /*
     * This overrides the original intent.
     */      
    setIntent(intent);
}
```